# Get all elements that have an attribute of itemprop

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using PHP DomDocument and trying to scrape out something that looks like this:

```
<div itemprop='movie'>Fight Club</div>
```

it could also look like this:

```
<span itemprop='musician'>Ozzy Osbourne</span>
```

I want to grab all of the `itemprop='n'` on the page and put them into an array to store their nodevalue, and the associated itemprop name. My code so far looks like this:

```
function getItemprops(){
        foreach($this->dom->getAttribute("itemprop") as $buffer) {
                $itempropList = array(
                    'theNodeValue' => $buffer->nodeValue,
                    'theItemprop'  => $buffer->getAttribute("itemprop")
                )
                return $itempropList;
        }
}
```

My code is supposed to get an array somewhere along the lines of:

```
array (
      array(
         0 =>
              "theNodeValue" => "Fight Club",
              "theItemprop"  => "movie"
         1 =>
              "theNodeValue" => "Fight Club",
              "theItemprop"  => "movie"
      )
)
```

Unfortunately, my code returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getAttribute()`.

So basically, I want to select all `itemprop=""`'s and put them in arrays.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use XPath to select all nodes with your required attribute first, then loop trhough the returned nodes to get text value and attribute value; like this

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($xmlsource);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]');  //this catches all elements with itemprop attribute
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
   // do your stuff here with $node
```